# R for loop if statement to print value from second df

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, return-value

I have a value in df1 that I want to print into df2 but they have an uneven number of rows

the kind of code I was thinking of using is something like

```
for(i in 1:dim(df1)[1]){
   df2$INT[if(df1$SN == df2$SN)
 {df1$INT[1]}
]}
```

But I just get errors spit out, I am not too familiar with for loops

df1

```
SN    ...   INT
1           0.015
2           0.01891
3           0.0208
4           ...
5           ...
```

df2

```
...     SN   INT
...     1    NA
...     1    NA
...     2    NA
...     3    NA
...     3    NA
...     ...  ...
```

df_OUTPUT

```
 ...     SN   INT
...     1     0.015
...     1     0.015
...     2     0.01891
...     3     0.0208
...     3     0.0208
...     ...  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you are looking to do is join the two tables based on the `SN` column. I'm assuming that in `df2` the entire `INT` column is `NA` values and can be dropped.

Base R solution

```
# drop INT from df2
df2 <- df2[-2]

# join based on SN column
merge(df1, df2)

#-----
  SN     INT
1  1 0.01500
2  1 0.01500
3  2 0.01891
4  3 0.02080
5  3 0.02080
```

---

`dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  select(-INT) %>%
  left_join(df1)

#----
Joining, by = "SN"
  SN     INT
1  1 0.01500
2  1 0.01500
3  2 0.01891
4  3 0.02080
5  3 0.02080
```

---

```
# Create dummy data
df1 <- data.frame(SN = 1:3, INT = c(0.015, 0.01891, 0.0208))
df2 <- data.frame(SN = c(1,1,2,3,3), INT = NA)
```